# Mesh deform-glitch on pose

Tags: mesh, armature

So, I'm working on a kinda "complex" anthro-character for a 3D Gam im making.

The character itself is finished - but I'm tweaking it a bit to make it look more real in different poses.

So tis character is a fox, who's snout is a little bit longer.
I've noticed that, if I rotate the head bone, everything works fine - except the snout.

The gums and teeth of the model are rotating a bit too far, so they get out of the jaw.
I've rigged the model from scratch and parented it with automatic weights and adjusted the weights after that.

There are only two shape key including the lower gums and teeth - but even if those are on 0, they're still glitched.

I've made a few screenshots to show what I actually mean - of course:

This is how the mouth usually looks:
[image: Normal Mouth]

This is how it looks after I rotate the head bone:
[image: Deformed Mouth]

And this is the weight paint:
[image: Weight painted mouth]

I would be very glad, if someone out there could help me...
I'm kind of an "advanced beginner" in Blender and I tried everything I could think of...